# How can I move a borderlands 2 character to my profile on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, borderlands-2

My brother has a character that I want, but I don't know how to get it onto my profile. He said that I can use it, but is there anyone that can help me link this character to my profile?

Comment: Can't you just take the data on a USBkey or something and add it on your profile?

Comment: just move his save folder to your profile. . .

Answer (score 3):

Borderlands characters are associated with the user account that is logged in. To access another players character, you will have to be logged in under that players playstation account.

There is no way to transfer characters between profiles.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way of moving characters between profiles. Only one thing that you can do is to move equipment.

You can connect in one game his and yours character. Then you can swap equipment.